# Items in ListView Disapper

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

So I test a PagerView and Both the two tabs doesn't work. Department use a ListView where Facility tab was supposed to show a GridView with images which are in drawable.  But none of them appear when I debug the app.

Here's the Department Fragment

```
public class DepartmentFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

private ArrayList<Department> dept_list = new ArrayList<Department>();
Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    context = rootView.getContext();
    ListView list_view = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dept_list);
    Database database = new Database(rootView.getContext());

    dept_list.addAll(Utils.SortDepartment(new ArrayList<Department>(database.getAllDepartment())));
    ArrayAdapter<Department> dept_adapter = new DepartmentListAdapter(context, dept_list);
    list_view.setAdapter(dept_adapter);
    list_view.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}

//when I click on it, it shows the details page correctly
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent info_intent;
    info_intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DepartmentInfo.class);
    info_intent.putExtra("deptname", dept_list.get(position).getDept_name());
    startActivity(info_intent);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

This is the Department list Adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Department department = this.getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dept_rowitem, null);
    }
    txt_deptname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dept_row_name);
    dept_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dept_row_image);
    txt_deptsummary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dept_row_detail);

    int resID = convertView.getResources().getIdentifier(department.getDept_img(), "drawable", "com.example.yangonuniversity");
    Bitmap bitmapimage = Utils.ImageDecode(resID, convertView);
    dept_image.setImageBitmap(bitmapimage);
    txt_deptname.setText(department.getDept_name());
    txt_deptsummary.setText(Utils.unescape(department.getDept_info().substring(0, 150) + "....."));
    return convertView;
}
```

And in the Facility Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_build, container, false);
    Database database = new Database(rootView.getContext());
    build_list.addAll(database.getAllBuildings());

    GridView grid_view = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.GridLayout1);
    grid_view.setAdapter(new BuildingListAdapter(rootView.getContext(), build_list));

    return rootView;
}
```

And here is the Adapter for Grid View in the Facility layout

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView img_view = new ImageView(context);
    int resID = convertView.getResources().getIdentifier(build_list.get(position).getBuild_img(), "drawable", "com.example.yangonuniversity");
    img_view.setImageResource(resID);
    img_view.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    img_view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return img_view;
}
```

Thanks for helping me with my project :D

EDIT: Added images
[image: Department Tab]

[image: Facility Tab]

Comment: The obvious question is if the data objects actually contain something or not.

Comment: @Luksprog did u mean Department/facility Object or Database?

Comment: @Luksprog I've tired taken out the log of Department components. They show respectively. Even the TextView.getText() shows what it meant to be in it. I think there's problem with inflater or convertView but I dun know what is it